# Windows Phone 7.5/8 - Optimal way to support multiple brands

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I am creating an app which needs to support multiple brands.
The majority of the  underlying code is the same for each customer.
The differences is only related to branding.
The, the following components are customer specific:

1. Images, logos, color schemes
2. Slogans, Terms of Conditions, Privacy Policies
3. App Icons

Does anyone know the optimal way to accomplish this in Windows Phone 7 & 8?
Particularly given the fact that the windows phone framework uses xaml and binding.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you don't have a ton of different brands to support, I'd suggest just creating multiple projects and then linking the files between them. Something similar to how you [support Windows Phone 7.5 and 8 with the same code base](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!co-development-and-porting-guide.html).

1) Create your base project with Brand A icons, logos.
2) Put your brand specific text in a resource file
3) Put your color schemes in a resource dictionary

When you're ready to create your next project you can either:

a) Just make a copy and update the images, text, and colors
or
b) Create another project and add the new images to it, add a new resource file, and create a separate resource dictionary, but link all the code and xaml files from the first project.

If you use method b it will mean you only have change your code and views once and it will update across projects.

Answer (score 0):

if this is supposed to be different apps submitted separately, you could just crack open the generated .xap file (it's really just a zip file) and replace the content files (ie images, text files etc). You could probably even automate this in a post-build commandline script,